# Implement an IDLE application screen saver in angular + electron

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I would like to implement a 'screen saver' behaviour in my **Angular** application built with **Electron** when the application is **idle** for an amount of time (let's say for 10 seconds). So, **if 10 seconds pass in the application without any action from the user** (or even the application itself?), a screen with a message should be shown, and this screen will be removed when user has any interaction with the application.

What would be the **recommended way**? Should I implement this behaviour in a custom way (set a timer which will be erased by any user action etc like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript) or is there any built-in solution in electron/Angular?

Please note that **I do not want to check for the general system's idle state**, just the application's.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to use [UserIdleService](https://github.com/rednez/angular-user-idle) in this way:

```
this._userIdle.onIdleStatusChanged().subscribe((isIdle) => {
        if (isIdle) {
            // code to show a screen saver image
        } else {
             this._userIdle.resetTimer();
             // code to hide the screen saver image
        }
    });
```

But I see the event getting fired every 1 second, despite my configuration for this module which is as following:

```
 UserIdleModule.forRoot(
        {
            idle: 100000,
            timeout: 1000000,
            ping: 60
        }
    )
```

What could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a check in [UserIdleService](https://github.com/rednez/angular-user-idle/blob/c886552514fc394f8e5c8db0d02498f797814422/projects/angular-user-idle/src/lib/angular-user-idle.service.ts#L170) code I realized that `idleSensitivity` parameter (which by default is `1` should be set in order to use it for inactivity check periodically). Example below:

```
 UserIdleModule.forRoot(
    {
        idle: 20,
        timeout: 20,
        idleSensitivity: 5,
        ping: 60
    }
)
```

This configuration, combined with the following subscription on `app.component.ts` works fine

```
this._userIdle.onIdleStatusChanged().subscribe((isIdle) => {
    if (isIdle) {
        // code to show a screen saver image
    } else {
         this._userIdle.resetTimer();
         // code to hide the screen saver image
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use observables for that, combined with the debounce function:

```
const mouseEvents = fromEvent(document, 'mousemove');

mouseEvents
  .pipe(debounceTime(10000))
  .subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
    // Idle screen logic here 
  });
```