# How to trigger a JavaScript Function when the user does no interaction (being inactive) for 1 mins?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page that requires me to trigger a JavaScript function when the user is inactive for 1 min.

this page mainly consists of `<form>` component.

How to create a function that trigger after 1 min of inactivity?

Comment: Use a timeout and clear/restart it every time the user is active on your page

Comment: can you give me some idea on how to check the user is active? Im sorry to ask such a beginner question :(

Comment: Well how do you define "active"? What counts as an "interaction"?

Comment: interacting with the form input. Is there any way so that I dont have to put "onInput" on every Input component?

Comment: The [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) bubbles, you can just listen to it on the form element or whole body

Comment: [This search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+idle) provides numerous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be similar to the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript) question. Setting a timer that resets every time there is a mousemove, keydown, scroll, or any event you want to listen to to determine inactivity:

```js
function triggerIfInactive() {
    let time;
    resetTimer();
    let events = ['mousedown', 'mousemove', 'keydown', 'scroll', 'mousewheel', 'touchstart']; // You can add/remove events as you need
    events.forEach(ev => document.addEventListener(ev, resetTimer, true));
    
    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(time); //Resets previous timer
        time = setTimeout(yourFunction, 60000) // Sets new timer after one minute
    }
};
windows.onload = () => triggerIfInactive();
```